# Vue.js - Vuelidate custom validator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I am using vuelidate, and need to do some custom validation but it involve taking into consideration different fields. For example: I have a radio button to select between `Month` and `Year`

If I select `Month` I will have a `Year Start` (2021, 2020,...) and `Month Start` (1, 2, 3...) dropdown and a `Year End` and `Month End` dropdown.

If I select `Year` I will have a `Year Start` (2021, 2020,...) and `Year End` (2021, 2020,...) dropdown.

My problem is that I need to validate for `month` option that `year start` is bigger than `year end` or that they can be equal and `month start` must be greater than `month end`.

And for `year` option `Year start` should be greater than `Year End`

I have this:

```
validations() {
  return {
    form: {
      startMonth: {},
      startYear: { required },
      endMonth: {},
      endYear: { required },
    }
  };
}
```

This is the logic I want to turn into a custom validator

```
if (this.option === "Year") {
  if (this.startYear > this.endYear) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

else if (this.option === "Month") {
  if (this.startYear > this.endYear) {
    return true;
  } else if (this.startYear == this.endYear && parseInt(this.startMonth) > parseInt(this.endMonth)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Any insight, help would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Possible Solution:

```
<script>
import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate';
import { required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        month: null,
        year: null,
        compareMonth: null,
        compareYear: null
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    disableApply() {
      return this.$v.form.$invalid;
    },
  },

  methods: {
    validateYear() {
      if (this.$v.form.year.$model > this.$v.form.compareYear.$model) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },

    validateMonth() {
      if (this.validateYear()) {
        return true;
      } 

      if (this.$v.form.year.$model === this.$v.form.compareYear.$model && parseInt(this.$v.form.month.$model) > parseInt(this.$v.form.compareMonth.$model)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },

  validations() {
    return {
      form: {
        month: { required, validateMonth: this.validateMonth },
        year: { required, validateMonth: this.validateYear },
        compareMonth: { required, validateMonth: this.validateMonth },
        compareYear: { required, validateMonth: this.validateYear },
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`accessing-component`](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-accessing-component) you can directly access the component instance using `this` keyword.
Try converting your code into Vue instance methods like

```
function validateYear() {
  if (this.startYear > this.endYear) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function validateMonth() {
  if (this.validateYear()) {
    return true;
  }
  if (this.startYear == this.endYear && parseInt(this.startMonth) > parseInt(this.endMonth)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and then apply them as custom validators:

```
validations() {
  return {
    form: {
      startMonth: {
        validateMonth: this.validateMonth
      },
      startYear: { 
        required,
        validateMonth: this.validateYear
      },
      endMonth: {
         validateMonth: this.validateMonth
      },
      endYear: { 
        required,
        validateMonth: this.validateYear
      },
    }
  };
}
```

P.S this could probably be optimised better using passed in value, `this.$v` values, ternary expressions etc, I just want to give you an idea to move forward

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!! This is actually working as expected, one issue though, it seems that the second `if` inside `validateMonth()` is never executed. When I select 2020 March and 2020 January... it should true since march (3) is larger than January (1)... I've updated my question with your solution, am I missing something to catch that scenario? Thanks!